# Incredibly strange empty space appearing below element with image inside

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I'm designing this site. Here's the HTML markup of this simple element:

http://thegrantmag.com

It's the image box at the bottom of the screen, below the content area. It has a strip of white space below it. I'm usually pretty good at CSS troubleshooting, but this one has me. I've tried removing all the elements with the element inspector. As long as that image exists, there is a thin strip of white space below.

UPDATE: I tried removing the img and replacing with a div. It always creates a few extra pixels below the element, no matter what gets put in there!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean? It's difficult to tell if what I'm seeing is an error or not.

Comment: See this image: http://cl.ly/FbJa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's better if you define `vertical-align:top` in your image.

```
img{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is better?

Comment: If you define display:block then you have to define float also but with 'vertical-align:top' you didn't have to define float

Comment: In this case the image was wrapped in a floating div, so it doesn't really matter. But this is absolutely a cleaner fix. +1

Answer (score 3):

Set your image to `display: block`, that should fix it.

Comment: Whoa! What was it set to? Isn't it block by default?

Comment: 10 seconds too late, I am... :P

Comment: @Jackson, no I think inline is default, but some browsers add the relentless space.

Comment: @JacksonGariety No, images are set to `display:inline` by default, and so they get `line-height`, which is messing up your container.

Comment: Yeah, inline is default. But what is the purpose of that (literally) un-calculated space? I've been doing CSS work for years and I'm surprised this is such a simple answer. Never encountered an element that created space like that before.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: images are inline by default, which means that they are also white space dependent. Browsers will usually render some white space around an inline element. Setting its display type to block gets rid of this. :)

Comment: I've never really found a satisfying answer to that myself. I think it has to do with ´line-height´ that is implied on inline elements.

Comment: Aha, that makes some sense. I'm just surprised I've never encountered this before.

Comment: @JacksonGariety - [Images, Tables, and Mysterious Gaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block` or `float:left` to the image's CSS.

See if that helps.